# How to use bouncer validation for textarea

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, input, textarea

I want to validate the email entered in a form(Which has `Textarea` intend of the `input` field). bouncer validation works perfectly for the `<input>` tag but it is not working for `<textarea>`. How to overcome this? Thanks. :)

Ref: https://codepen.io/belt-basya/pen/MWmNrER